# Separate trainX and trainY using Tensorflow 2 input pipeline for multi-loss training

Tags: python, tensorflow, pipeline

I am building a network takes one picture as input and outputs two predictions, and the loss function calculated from both predictions. So:

Input(trainX): **RGBD**
Output1(trainGT): **GT**
Output2(trainError): **error**

As I am using TF's standard input pipeline, it zips the input and targets. However, when I define loss function, I need separate the two targets. Here is my code for input pipeline:

```
@tf.function
def load_image(point_file):
    name = tf.strings.split(point_file,'/')[-1]
    GT = tf.io.read_file(GT_path + name)
    RGBD = tf.io.read_file(RGBD_path + name)
    error = tf.io.read_file(error_path + name)
    GT = tf.image.decode_png(GT)
    RGBD = tf.image.decode_png(RGBD)
    error = tf.image.decode_png(error)[:, :, 0]

    GT = tf.cast(GT, tf.float32)// 255.0
    RGBD = tf.cast(RGBD, tf.float32)/ 255.0
    error = tf.cast(error, tf.float32)
    error = tf.reshape(error, 1024)

    return RGBD, GT, error

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(point_path + 'train/*.png')
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(load_image,
                                  num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE).repeat()

test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(point_path+'test/*.png')
test_dataset = test_dataset.map(load_image)
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

Later in the fit function what I want to do is:

```
losses = {
    "GT_output": loss_functions.weighted_dice_loss,
    "error_output": tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
}
lossWeights = {"GT_output": 0.9, "error_output": 0.1}

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=losses, loss_weights=lossWeights,)

model.fit(x=trainX,
    y={"GT_output": trainGT, "error_output": trainError},
    validation_data=(testX,
        {"GT_output": testGT, "error_output": testError}),
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    verbose=1)
```

But is there a way to separate trainX, trainGT and trainError from train_dataset?

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```py
take_n = 1000
trainGT = train_dataset.take(take_n)
trainError = train_dataset.skip(take_n)
```